# SQL вставка только что отредактированных записей в таблицу

Tags: sql, sql-server

Прошу вашей помощи в работе с триггерами.

Есть база данных, состоящая из двух таблиц: реестр и история изменений. Мне необходимо создать триггер, который при изменении записи в реестре добавлял бы эту же запись в таблицу истории. Триггер after update я написал, но он вставляет все содержащиеся в реестре записи, а не только измененную.

Возможно ли так написать триггер, чтобы при обновлении реестра в историю вставлялась только обновленная запись (может это делается через Where)? Заранее благодарю.

Вот текущий код, который вставляет все записи, а не только отредактированную:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ReestrTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[Реестр]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO dbo.История_записей (Дата_записи,Время_записи,Инв_номер,Статус) SELECT GETDATE(),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,Инв_номер,Статус FROM dbo.Реестр;
END
```

Comment: `from inserted`

Comment: @teran сработало, спасибо большое!

Comment: В Sql Server есть исторические таблицы: [Temporal tables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В MS SQL предусмотрены две специальные временные таблицы, доступные только из триггеров: [inserted и deleted](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables)

В триггерах на update таблица inserted содержит новые версии всех измененных строка, а deleted — старые.

В вашем случае код получается такой:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ReestrTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[Реестр]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO dbo.История_записей (Дата_записи,Время_записи,Инв_номер,Статус)
    SELECT GETDATE(),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,Инв_номер,Статус
    FROM inserted;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей лучше использовать [темпоральные таблицы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16).

[Тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNdOyqNEeeQ&ab_channel=YuriyLebedev) можно посмотреть про них.